# Use functions inside standalone (w/o Laravel) blade template

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I'm doing a simple static website where I installed the standalone version of Blade (so no Laravel) to use as a template engine. I tried declaring a function inside a template and using it but I'm getting an undefined function error.

How would I go about doing this? And while at it, how would I use functions defined in external files?

Comment: Could you share your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I was doing wrong but it's working now, here's an example for future reference:

```php
<?php
function renderSomething($foo) {
    ob_start()
    ?>
    <div>{{$foo}}</div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
?>

<div>{!! renderSomething("foo") !!}</div>
```